# Do I need to register as a freelancer and where?

Tags: contracts, legal, taxes, germany, travel

I'm german but living since 3 years in the Philippines. I work currently for a local company and have a working visa.
Now I got a offer from a german company to work remote as a freelancer for them as a Software Engineer.
They ask me if I can do any freelancer or business registration. I researched this but can't find a answer how to handle this.
As soon as I don't work any more with the Philippine company I would have only a tourist visa so I'm not sure if I could register as freelancer here. Also when I checked the German law it seems to me if I don't have a residency in Germany and I already unregistered myself, then I have to follow the countries law where I am, not the German one.

Any advice what is right? Do I even need to register myself? What to say to the company?

Comment: I think you should acctualy look for a lawyer that can answer that question, either in Philippines or in Germany.
Also, you could maybe contact a helping center of the government? I don't know how it works there... Or maybe ask the company about it, there's no shame in not knowing something you aren't supposed to know.

Comment: I don't know which country it is, but as far as I know, freelancers don't need to register anywhere

Answer (score 2):

I don't know specifically for a country, but as far as I know freelancers don't need to register anywhere (might be different for different countries).

If I work with a client or a company not located in my country, I just make a contract with them. Use invoices for quoting my services. I don't think you need to register anywhere. As freelancing is a kind of sole proprietorship, it does not need to be registered.

However, that company can sign a contract for the work done.